# angular.js and require js together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm creating local app on nw.js with using angular.js. And i feel that i do something wrong, when in my controller i write something like this:

```
.controller('UserSettingsCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $translate) {
     var fs = require('fs');
     var path = require('path');

     var file = 'user_settings.json';
     var filePath = path.join(nw.App.dataPath, file);
}
```

Is this a right way, to use require in every controller where i need node.js modules or other libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are almost there, just I think you have to set references to any serives or objects you are injecting before using:

```
 app.register.controller('UserSettingsCtrl',
    ['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'translate', function ($scope, $mdDialog, translate) {
     var fs = require('fs');
     var path = require('path');

     var file = 'user_settings.json';
     var filePath = path.join(nw.App.dataPath, file);
}]);
```

Comment: I know this, my question was about: "Is this normal to use require in every controller" or better create global variables or (your answer). What do you recommend